# MySQL aggregate column as set of distinct values

Tags: mysql, group-by, set, aggregate-functions

I want to aggregate a column as a set of values.

Let's consider the following schema

```
A, B, C
'a', 'b', 'c'
'a', 'b', 'd'
'a', 'c', 'd'
'b', 'a', 'c'
'b', 'd', 'a'
```

I need a result like this

```
A, B, C
'a', ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd']
'b', ['a', 'd'], ['c', 'a']
```

I tried searching for a set aggregation function but can't find any useful thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can `group by A` and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to collect the distinct `B`s and `C`s:

```
SELECT A,
       CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B SEPARATOR ', '), ']') B,
       CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT C SEPARATOR ', '), ']') C
FROM tablename
GROUP BY A
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2d6e43cc3a44dc92b4938d9cd5ffc48c).